# Can't seem to get Prettyphoto to work

Tags: jquery, html, prettyphoto

Been trying for hours now, can't seem to find the problem.
http://sabinequardon.dk/poooort/index.html

I've made sure it's linking to the right files etc, but it just doesn't open in prettyphoto.
It's prob. a really easy problem, and maybe it's me who've just been starring at it for too long :-(

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You never invoke prettyPhoto...

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("a[rel^='prettyPhoto']").prettyPhoto();
});
```

You're loading jQuery twice, first and foremost. And that overhead is unnecessary. Second, you need to move ALL the scripts BESIDES the one I placed above into the  region.

```
...
<head>
  <script src="assets/js/jquery-1.6.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
  <script src="assets/js/jquery.prettyPhoto.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
  <!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
  <![endif]-->
  <script src="assets/js/jquery.quicksand.js"></script>
  <script src="assets/js/script.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  ...
  <!---end of the body-->
  <script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
$("a[rel^='prettyPhoto']").prettyPhoto();
  });
  </script>
</body>
```

Comment: Hm, thanks.
I've tried it now, but it still doesn't work. :-/

Comment: @Sabine Quardon I literally copy and pasted that code into the console on your wesbite, and pretty Photo fired.

Comment: Hm, where did you put it? Maybe i'm placing it the wrong place? :O

Comment: @Sabine Quardon before the closing </body> tag.

Comment: It's weird it doesn't work.
works if i put it in the console too, but not in my html file :s

Comment: How are you loading the elements into the DOM? We might have to defer the function to a static parent element which the click can bubble to.

Comment: Hi..
tried, but still doesn't work.
Really don't get it. it's supposed to be easy to use :-O

Comment: if i remove the other scripts, it works. but i kinda need those :-S

Comment: Gonna find another solution!
thanks for taking the time. will make your answer the correct one :-)

Comment: I was struggling with the same problem, and this solution worked perfectly for me. Thanks!